# Java String not found within larger string

Tags: java, string

What I'm trying to do is take a list of my personal browsing history and check it against a VERY long list of domains. When the domain is found within a record of my history, I want the domain printed out to a file. I have tried using both the String.indexOf() and String.contains() methods to no avail. I will post below what I currently have using the contains method. I had it working earlier with just junk data and a list of keywords instead of domains, but when I switched to the actual parameters instead of what I was using to test it, it simply broke.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
public class Comparator {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
            File sites = new File("sites.txt");
            File history = new File("history.txt");
            BufferedReader sitesS = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (sites));
            BufferedReader historyS = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (history));
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter("output.txt");
            ArrayList<String> historyL = new ArrayList();
            String read = new String("");
            String compare = new String("");
            boolean index = true;
            boolean match = false;

            while ((read = historyS.readLine()) != null) {
                    read = read.toLowerCase();
                    historyL.add(read);
            }
            historyS.close();
            System.out.println("After History is closed.");
            while ((read = sitesS.readLine()) != null) {
                    read = read.toLowerCase();
                    for (int i = 0; i < historyL.size() && match == false; i++) {
                            compare = historyL.get(i).toString();
                            compare = compare.toLowerCase();
                            index = compare.contains(read);
                            System.out.println(index);
                            if (index == true) {
                                    System.out.println("Output should be in the file");
                                    output.println(read);
                                    match = true;
                            }
                    }
                    match = false;
            }
            sitesS.close();
            output.close();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Small snippet of the history.txt file that I'm testing with: http://pastebin.com/Ju4cPv9p
The sites.txt testing set I'm working with: http://pastebin.com/aiurExWb

Comment: There are various things I'd change in this code, but it's hard to tell exactly what's wrong without seeing the data - we need to be able to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Jon is right, the "contains" operation is the weak point if the strings are similar but not exactly a part of the other. Perhaps a regex may be more accurate in the later case.

Comment: As pointed out above, we need to see the data. If you're simply trying to see if the base domain matches, I'd recommend using string.startsWith() rather than contains().

Comment: Your code works fine. You're perhaps just not reading/writing the files you think you are. Use your debugger to execute the lines of code line by line, inspect the values of the variables, and understand what is wrong i your assumptions/inputs.

Comment: I've used println to spit out the data that's being read, and I can guarantee that I am reading the correct files. Index is never true. I've also tried this with indexof and the index was always -1. as far as the data itself goes, I suppose I can upload two small snippets of the data currently in the set I'm testing and see if you guys can figure it out. The problem with using startsWith is that the addresses do not start with the domain. They start with Http://www. and even if I strip that off, some of them are https. Differentiating between them and stripping it off is an option I guess.

Comment: Do the data files contain some extra whitespace (trailing space, trailing tabs)? Maybe you can look at the hex dump of the files and see, if there are some suspicious characters.

Comment: The lines of the history.txt file all seem to have a trailing tab. That shouldn't mess with the contains method though, shouldn't it? I mean, they all get pulled out as one singular line just fine.

Comment: I've even tried adding a branching if/else statement that appends http://, https://, http://www., https://www. to the front of the string to see if it startsWith() to no avail. I've also looked at the binary of history.txt and the only things at the end of the line is a tab and a carriage return.